# Examples of homeomorphisms between the real numbers and the positive real numbers?

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology, metric-spaces, examples-counterexamples

I'm interested in homeomorphisms between the real numbers, $\mathbb{R}$, and the positive real numbers, $(0,\infty)$--where both spaces have the topology induced by the metric $d(x,y)=|x-y|$.

Here is a couple of easy examples, $f:(0,\infty)\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$, I could think of

$$f(x)=\ln(x),\quad\quad\quad f(x)=\frac{x^{\alpha}-\gamma }{x^\beta},$$

where $\alpha,\beta,\gamma>0$ and $\alpha>\beta$. What other homeomorphisms are there?

EDIT: The motivation for the above question is to search for initial value problems

$\dot{x}=f(x),\quad\quad x_0\in\mathbb{R}^n_{>0}$

whose solutions can be mapped `nicely' to those of a linear system of ODEs on $\mathbb{R}^n$

$\dot{z}=Az,\quad\quad z_0\in\mathbb{R}^n.$

That way the analysis of the former, can be done by simply studying the later (which, generally will be much easier).

Comment: What do you hope to learn from such a list? There are verrrrrrrrrrrrrrry many such functions.

Comment: So you want a list of continuous functions from $\mathbb{R}^+$ to $\mathbb{R}$? "big-list" doesn't even begin to cover the breadth of that. Is there some specific criteria you want these to have?

Comment: I was hoping to use the functions to come up with examples of systems of ODEs--whose trajectories are confined on the non-negative orthant-- can be easily analysed because they can be mapped to a linear system on $\mathbb{R}^n$. Sorry if this question irritates anyone, I'm not looking for an exhaustive list (I recognise that would be silly) just a few examples.

Comment: @jkn can you include that in the question then? Looking for examples that work well with that application seems like a much more reasonabe scope.

Comment: @RobertMastragostino Thanks for the suggestion, I have adjusted the title and the question.

Comment: It's really bad form to use the word "homeomorphism" when you are really looking for differentiable functions, for what its worth. Homeomorphisms is a very broad term, and only depend on topologies, while differentiability is about a lot of additional information.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[Posted before motivation was added. Still might be useful.]

To find all homeomorphism between $X$ and $Y$, find one, $f:X\to Y$, and then find all self-homeomorphisms $Y\to Y$. Then every homeomorphism $X\to Y$ can be written as $h\circ f$ for some homeomorphism $h:Y\to Y$.

A homeomorphism $\mathbb R\to \mathbb R$ is a strictly monotonic continuous function that is unbounded above and below.

For diffeomorphisms, you can do the same thing.